# GeoServer - labels not working correctly

Tags: geoserver, leaflet, sld

Currently having a few issues with GeoServer not displaying our labels correctly. The code in question is here:

```
<Fill>
          <CssParameter name="fill">
            <ogc:Literal>#000000</ogc:Literal>
          </CssParameter>
          <CssParameter name="fill-opacity">
            <ogc:Literal>0.75</ogc:Literal>
          </CssParameter>
        </Fill>
        <VendorOption name="spaceAround">-1</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="conflictResolution">false</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="partials">true</VendorOption>
        <VendorOption name="goodnessOfFit">0</VendorOption>

      </TextSymbolizer>

    </Rule>
  </FeatureTypeStyle>

</UserStyle>
```

That's at the end of my style file. From what answers I've already looked at, this should be okay. However, labels appear and disappear at different zoom levels, as below:

[image: Image 1 - zoomed far out, labels in middle-bottom missing]

[image: Image 2 - zoomed in a bit more, labels towards right missing]

[image: Image 3 - zoomed in to closest level, labels in bottom-left missing]

I've turned guttering up to 100px, and also the metatiling to 1x1, but this is still happening. This does appear to have occurred a few other times on posts, but I think I've done everything they've done (as described above).

Comment: What is the geometry of your label?

Comment: Sorry @IanTurton - don't quite understand the geometry of the label. If you mean the geometry underneath that it is attached to, it is a point layer, projected in EPSG 4283. Sorry - am pretty new to GeoServer.